# NSString rounding to closest whole number when I try to +2.50

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsstring, xcode4.2

I'm trying to make a `UILabel` count up in decimals but it's rounding to the nearest whole. Here is the code:

```
int currentTime = [totalPrice.text intValue];
    int newTime = currentTime + 2.50;
    totalPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.00", newTime];
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I couldn't find any other articles on StackOverflow that were helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is a datatype that only stores integers (whole numbers).  Use `float` or `double` for decimal numbers, or NSDecimalNumber if you need exact representations.

```
float currentType = [totalPrice.text floatValue];
float newTime = currentTime + 2.5;
totalPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", newTime];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `float` type for those values if you're going to be working with decimals like that.

`int` is meant to be used with whole numbers.